# Can't grow extended partition (unmounted)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have an extended partition `/dev/sda`4 inside it is a partition `/dev/sda5`, and outside the extended partition is unallocated space. I want to grow `/dev/sda4` so that there is no unallocated space outside `/dev/sda4`. My attempt to do this has failed. I even tried with a live USB, but that didn't work.

Partitions:

[image: partitions]

Growing partition:

[image: growing partition]

error: `Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.`

[image: error:unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition]

*Edit:* I used KDE Partition Manager and it worked.

Comment: Standard tools only allow expansion of partitions using space already within the extended partition thus your error. Some file-systems allow you to have space over multiple disks (including inside & outside of logical or extended partitions, but not ext4). I'd likely use the space as a separate partition and mount it as a directory if I didn't want to backup/restore the data in order to re-create an extended partition.  Wait & other may have other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Growing the extended partition worked using KDE Partition Manager (*partitionmanager*) file, disk and partition management utility for KDE.